# WCSession is not reachable for sending messages

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos, wcsession

I want to trigger few events to my watch extension app from the iOS app but I'm getting the error saying WCSession is not reachable. All my events are time-sensitive, So I can't wait for the user to turn on the watch display to trigger the events.

1. Is there any way where I can achieve this using local notification?
2. Is it possible to trigger watchOS launch, so that WCSession becomes reachable without user action?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way where I can achieve this using local notification?

As far as I know, a notification does not change the reachability. You could debug its behaviour by using this on the iOS side to check if it becomes available.

`func sessionReachabilityDidChange(_ session: WCSession) {}`

I would recommend you to take a look at [Extended Runtime Sessions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/using_extended_runtime_sessions), although it won't be running 24/7 in the background.